# How to choose and join corporation in 0 or wormhole (with low SP char)?

Tags: eve-online

In the zero sec and wormholes of EvE universe are the greatest possibilities to make ISK. Is there some good way for low SP char to find and join good corporation in 0 or wormhole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some organizations do recruit newer players you may have a couple of problems.

1) Suspicion: Some of the more paranoid alliances (read: most of them) fear spies in their ranks, and brand new characters are inherently suspicious.

2) Not up to muster: Although great wealth is available in these regions they mostly go to those who can take and hold it. When I first came to the game I moved to null within a month and was miserable because I was flying with people with years of SP that could simply do everything so much better as to leave me more or less function-less. I couldn't even fight in the areas they were to make money without being ripped apart by the NPCs.

While low SP life in null/wh is possible, I recommend taking your time and learning what EVE has to offer you. There are many good environments to get integrated with the larger system. Red V Blue, EVEUni, and Faction Warfare all present wonderful opportunities for newer players getting their feet.

If you DO decide to go for one of the WH/Null groups, find one that has a training program and accepts newer players. A lot of them will post in the recruitment boards on the EVE-O forums.

Comment: BTW Aideron Robotics is hiring :P